# jQuery compare form input arrays, color the difference

Tags: jquery

I have a form with two array inputs as follows (this is inside a while loop in PHP):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="ordered[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rso['boxes']; ?>" readonly >
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="received[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="">
```

"Ordered" is pulled from the database. "Received" is what the user must fill in. What I'm trying to do, is compare the two values and color the "received" value based on the difference, ie. if 9 boxes were orders and 5 were received, then the value filled in the "received" fields must be changed to red. Likewise, if 9 boxes are ordered and 12 received, the value must be blue.

Here is my complete code in jQuery:

```
//When input value of received is changed, fire this function   
        $("input[name^='received']").on('change',function(){

            //Check how many rows there are 
            var n = $("input[name^='ordered']").length;

            //Get array for boxes received from suppliers   
            var array = $("input[name^='received']");

            //Get array for what was ordered    
            var boxes = $("input[name^='ordered']");    

            //Loop through the rows 
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                //Get value of ordered
                bo =  boxes.eq(i).val();

                //Get value of received
                br =  array.eq(i).val();

                if (br != "") {

                    //If received is less than ordered, font red
                    if (br < bo) {
                        $("input[name='received["+i+"]']").css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                        $("input[name='remarks["+i+"]']").css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'});

                    //Else if received is more than ordered, font blue
                    } else if (br > bo) {
                        $("input[name='received["+i+"]']").css({'color':'blue', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                        $("input[name='remarks["+i+"]']").css({'color':'blue', 'font-weight':'bold'});

                    //Else if equal, also make blue 
                    } else if (br === bo) {
                        $("input[name='received["+i+"]']").css({'color':'blue', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                        $("input[name='remarks["+i+"]']").css({'color':'blue', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                    }

                }


            }   


        });
```

This code works, but as soon as "ordered" is a value with two digits, the value in "received" does not color as expected. Seemingly, if I have 10 as "ordered" for example, "received" only colors correctly if 1 is entered.

I've tried using the "each" function but I don't know how to compare two arrays and then color the difference.

Comment: you should cast the string inputs to numbers, for example: `bo =  parseInt(boxes.eq(i).val());` if you have floats use `parseFloat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should cast the string inputs to number-types so you can rely on the comparison to work as you expect.

```
            br =  parseInt(array.eq(i).val());

            //if the value was "" parseInt will result as NaN which is false, so now check if br evaluates true or false
            if (br) {
```

if you have decimals use parseFloat()